# Canon LBP 5200 on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, laser-printer

Any chance of getting a Canon LBP 5200 colour laser printer working on Windows 7 64-bit ?

... or should I permanently close the door on Canon and their products ?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to installed such as this, but it still doesn't work.

It should be possible to get it working with LBP5200 drivers for Windows 7 32 Bit.

Answer (score 0):

LBP5200 is not compatible with x64 Windows7. But according to [this thread](http://www.sevenforums.com/drivers/10658-canon-lbp5000-64-bit-drivers-3.html) it's possible to get it working with LBP5000 drivers. You should find it on [this page](http://software.canon-europe.com/products/0010308.asp), look for *Printer Driver (x64 Edition) (R1.13 Ver.3.10)*